# Optimising C++ Code

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm trying the classic subset sum problem on an online judge. However, the difference this time is that n<=30 so the maximum operations can go up to 30*2^30. I already have some working code below. However, the time limit of the program is 1 second and my program hovers between 0.5 to 1.1 seconds. This results in a TLE although I've tried to speed up my code as best as I can. Do you guys have any tips on how I might be able to speed up and optimise my code further? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

unsigned power(unsigned x, unsigned y){        //pow function
    unsigned sum=x;
    for (int i=1;i<=y-1;i++)
        sum*=x;
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    unsigned t, n, p, sum, sum2, tmpsum=0;
    unsigned bars[32];
    bool found;
    scanf("%u", &t);
    while (t--){
        tmpsum=0;
        found=false;
        scanf("%u %u", &n, &p);
        for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
            scanf("%u",&bars[i]);
            tmpsum+=bars[i];
        }
        if (tmpsum<n)found=false;
        unsigned end=power(2,p)-1;          //counting from the end and from the start
        for (unsigned i=0;i<power(2,p)&&tmpsum>=n;i++){       //counting from 1 to 2^n in binary
            sum=0;
            sum2=0;
            for (unsigned j=0;j<p;j++){
                if (i&(1<<j))
                    sum+=bars[j];
                if (end&(1<<j))     //counting from the end and start at the same time
                    {sum2+=bars[j];end--;}
            }
            if (sum==n||sum2==n)
                {found=true;break;}
        }
        cout<<(found==true?"YES":"NO")<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Man, the exponentiation function can be vastly improved. Look here for more information: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/21/efficient-integer-exponentiation-algorithms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing ugly code doesn't make it faster, separate your statements onto different lines, i.e replace `{sum2+=bars[j];end--;}` with

```
{
    sum2 += bars[j];
    --end;
}
```

On to the question: your major time loss is likely here:

```
for (unsigned i=0;i<power(2,p)&&tmpsum>=n;i++){
```

Which will, unless you've got a particularly good compiler, be calculating `power(2, p)` once for every cycle through the loop, this is completely unneeded. Pre-calculate it.

```
int pow2p = power(2, p);
for (unsigned i=0;i<pow2p&&tmpsum>=n;i++){
```

Also, doing powers of 2 this way is very slow, so use `<<` instead (`1<<p == power(2, p)`).

**Edit** Since this has been accepted, I'll collect together minor points from other answers/comments:

1. As Nim points out, the `tmpsum>=n` check doesn't need to be done every loop as neither `n` nor `tmpsum` change during the loop.
2. As Karthik T point out, the line `if (tmpsum<n)found=false;` is redundant, `found` can never be anything but `false` at this point.

Comment: One more thing to add, the check `tmpsum>=n` is redundant in that loop, neither appears to be touched in the loop, just rewrite the if condition about to bypass the loop..

Comment: also, use `std::pow` from `<cmath>` rather than hand-rolling, the compiler may optimize better for powers of two...

Answer (score 3):

Move `power(2,p)` outside the loop.

```
for (unsigned i=0;i<power(2,p)&&tmpsum>=n;i++)
                      ^^^^
```

Comment: bit shift will be faster IMHO.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev both should happen for best results I expect.

Answer (score 3):

Use bit shift for computing degrees of two.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, [Avoid Branching](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-the-cost-of-branch-misprediction).
For example:

```
if (i&(1<<j))
    sum+=bars[j];
```

can be written as

```
sum+=bars[j] * ((i&(1<<j))>>j);
```

Granted, it makes already hard to read code even harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tmpsum<n)found=false;
```

This line achieves nothing, `found` is already `false`.

```
1<<j
```

Is being calculated twice, can be reduced to once by storing the result.

Comment: It's unlikely that the compiler won't already cache 1<<j.

Answer (score 0):

for starters you can move `power(2,p)` out of the for loop

```
for (unsigned i=0, end=power(2,p); i<end && tmpsum>=n; i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. power(2, p) is equal to 1 << p
2. Define sum and sum2 as register variables.

   register unsigned sum, sum2;

Comment: Register is very, very unlikely to make _any_ difference at all.

Comment: Unless this is Turbo C++ or some other 20 year-old compiler, the use of `register` will have near zero effect - if it has any effect at all, it's just as likely to be detrimental as it is to be good. Modern compilers, such as gcc later than (at least) 2.95 [the latest released version is 4.8 or so] will use registers whether you ask for it or not whenever possible.